# Problems with the function(char*prompt)- computation

Tags: c

I'm writing a program that compute a total salary by calculating the variable ratePerHour, hoursWorked, bonus, overtimeSalary. Everything works fine but when I try to run it it doesn't store the input values of any variables and it doesn't do the computation.

I think the problems are because of something wrong of my readNumber function:

```
double readNumber(char *prompt) {
    double val;
    //print the prompt:
    printf("%s", prompt);
    scanf(" %lf", &val);

    if (scanf("%lf", &val) != 1) {
      printf("Invalid input.\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

Also another problem is the program should ask the user if he is receiving bonus or not and if the user put `n` it shouldn't ask him to enter the bonus, but for some reason my program does.

```
char readYesOrNo(char *prompt) {
     char yn = 'n';
     //display the prompt:
     printf("%s", prompt);

     yn = scanf(" %c", &yn);

     //return the value
     return(yn);
 }
```

and in the end it shows my computation as zero so I think there's something wrong with storing the values I will attach the picture of what my program look like. I would really appreciate any kind of help since I've been really struggling with it.

[image]

Comment: Your code sample is munged, so it is not possible to tell what is code and what is comment.   That makes it hard for people to help.   A statement of the form `yn = scanf("%c", &yn)` means `scanf()` will read a value into `yn`, and then immediately discard it (by overwriting with the return value of `scanf()` - truncated from `int` to `char`).

Comment: You don't want `exit(0);` in `readNumber()`; you probably want `return val;` instead.  Also, please use comment notation to embed comments in your code.  Your code is very C-like and very un-C++-like.

Comment: Post text as text, not images!

Answer (score 1):

In `readnumber()` you should return `val` instead or `exit(0)`.

In `readYesorNo()` you are returning the return value of `scanf` which is `1` even if you input a `N`.

Answer (score 1):

How many times do you think you need to read `val`??

```
double readNumber(char *prompt) {
    double val;            /* you have 1 val */
    print the prompt:
    printf("%s", prompt);
    scanf(" %lf", &val);           /* you read it the 1st time here (unneeded) */

    if (scanf("%lf", &val) != 1) { /* you read whatever the next num is here */
      printf("Invalid input.\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

You are better served getting rid of the unneeded initial read and returning a `double` as you have declared the function to do, e.g.:

```
double readNumber (const char *prompt) 
{
    double val;
    printf ("%s", prompt);          /* print the prompt */
    if (scanf ("%lf", &val) != 1) { /* read/validate the double value */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: Invalid input.\n");

        exit(0);  /* you can handle the error how ever you like here 
                   * since you are returning a double, indicating success or
                   * failure by numeric return is a difficult proposition.
                   */
    }
    return val;
}
```

(**note:** passing `prompt` as `const char *prompt` will assist the compiler in further optimizing the routine -- knowing `prompt` isn't subject to change)

(as you go further in C, you may consider reading a line at a time with `fgets` and then  parsing the values you need from the buffer with `sscanf`, or using a pair of character pointers, which allows decoupling the read from the parse/conversion providing for more flexible handling of input contingencies).

give `readNumber` a try as modified above (and note: `readnumber` avoids `camelCase` variables which are not used with much favor in C as they are in C++, it's a style thing, so it's up to you, but it will certainly stand out in ways you may not want it to for those reading your C code)

The other answers have covered the `scanf` return of `yn` that is not doing what you think it is, I'll not repeat that here.